# Get text area value and store it in a div with line breaks using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a text from Textarea element and save the text into a div keeping line breaks obtained by pressing Enter key. But the code I am using does not seem to be good enough :)
Could you please take a look at the code below and share a suggestions on how to achieve such result:

JS

```
var div = $('div');
var textarea = $('textarea');

textarea.keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        div.text(textarea.val() + "\n") 
    }
})
```

Result div:

[image]

Result using 
 instead of the \n

[image]

Comment: use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

`<br/>` instead of `\n` for new line in **Html**

Also use `.append()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Updated the question with another screenshot

Comment: @EmilGurbanov You should ise `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Nope, didn't help

Comment: @EmilGurbanov what should be the output and what you are getting?

Comment: each word should start from new line in the div

Comment: @EmilGurbanov use `.append()`  instead of  `.text()`

Comment: Yep, this helped :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Partially actually, now the problem is that anytime enter is released it grabs the whole text and append the break to it. So the text now looks like this: first, first second, first second third

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128340/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-emil-gurbanov).